# Definition of Hecke operators on Jacobi forms (with level and character)

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms

How are the Hecke operators on the space of Jacobi forms $J_{k,m}(M,\chi)$ with weight $k$, index $m$, level $M$ and Dirichlet character $\chi\pmod M$ is defined? A reference will be good enough.

Some background - for the full modular group $\Gamma_1=\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, the theory of Hecke operators are well explained in the Eichler-Zagier book, *The Theory of Jacobi Forms*. For $\phi \in J_{k,m}(\Gamma_1)$, it is defined by
$$ (\phi|T_l)(\tau,z) = l^{k-4}\sum_{\substack{\Gamma_1\backslash M_2(\mathbb{Z}), \det(M)=l^2\\gcd(M)=\square}} \sum_{X\in \mathbb{Z}^2\backslash l\mathbb{Z}^2} \phi|_{k,m} M|_m X $$ Action of $T_l$ on the Fourier coefficients of $\phi$ is also given later, along with the commutative relation (action of $T_lT_{l'}$).

Where can one find similar definitions and relations for a general level and character? [This](https://doi.org/10.1215/21562261-1503791) paper of Ibukiyama gives the definition for a prime $p\not|M$ by
$$ \phi|T(p) = p^{k-4} \sum_M \sum_{X\in \mathbb{Z}^2\backslash p\mathbb{Z}^2}\chi(\alpha)\phi|_{k,1}[M/p]|_1 X $$ for $\phi\in J_{k,1}(M,\chi)$, where $\alpha$ is the $(1,1)$ component of $M$, and $M$ varies over a set of representatives for $$\Gamma_0(M)\backslash \{ A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d \end{smallmatrix}\right)\in\Gamma_0(M): \det(A)=p^2, \,gcd(a,M)=1, \, gcd(A)=\square \}.$$  A similar definition is also given for the case prime $p|M$, and set of representatives for each of the cases is also given, along with the action of these Hecke operators on the coefficients $c_{\phi}(D,r)$.

Question is, how will the definition for general $T_l$ look like? How can they be computed from the definitions given for $T_p$?